# Variance-Covariance matrix of the value at each level instead of that for deviation from base level in lme4

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

Consider the following models - `model1` and `model2`.

```
library(lme4)
library(agridat)
data(john.alpha)
dat <- john.alpha

# `rep`, `block` and `gen` are categorical variables (factors)
str(dat)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ plot : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ rep  : Factor w/ 3 levels "R1","R2","R3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ block: Factor w/ 6 levels "B1","B2","B3",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ gen  : Factor w/ 24 levels "G01","G02","G03",..: 11 4 5 22 21 10 20 2 23 14 ...
 $ yield: num  4.12 4.45 5.88 4.58 4.65 ...

# models
model1 <- lmer(yield ~ 1 + rep + (1|gen) + (1|rep:block), dat)
model2 <- lmer(yield ~ 1 + rep + gen + (1|rep:block), dat)
```

As `rep` and `gen` are factors, `vcov()` gives the variances of the differences in the expected value from the first level.

```
vcov(model1)
3 x 3 Matrix of class "dpoMatrix"
            (Intercept)       repR2       repR3
(Intercept)  0.02105802 -0.01510377 -0.01510377
repR2       -0.01510377  0.03020754  0.01510377
repR3       -0.01510377  0.01510377  0.03020754
vcov(model2)
26 x 26 Matrix of class "dpoMatrix"
            (Intercept)         repR2         repR3        genG02        genG03        genG04        genG05
(Intercept)  0.04748541 -1.387503e-02 -1.387503e-02 -3.623006e-02 -3.594567e-02 -3.594567e-02 -3.317053e-02
repR2       -0.01387503  2.775005e-02  1.387503e-02 -1.723344e-17 -1.742046e-17 -1.742099e-17 -1.607552e-17
repR3       -0.01387503  1.387503e-02  2.775005e-02 -1.657859e-17 -1.709303e-17 -1.709409e-17 -1.577335e-17
genG02      -0.03623006 -1.723344e-17 -1.657859e-17  7.246011e-02  3.623006e-02  3.617117e-02  3.343504e-02
genG03      -0.03594567 -1.742046e-17 -1.709303e-17  3.623006e-02  7.189134e-02  3.566128e-02  3.551049e-02
genG04      -0.03594567 -1.742099e-17 -1.709409e-17  3.617117e-02  3.566128e-02  7.189134e-02  3.571109e-02
genG05      -0.03317053 -1.607552e-17 -1.577335e-17  3.343504e-02  3.551049e-02  3.571109e-02  6.630786e-02
genG06      -0.03596555 -1.743436e-17 -1.711101e-17  3.577827e-02  3.571109e-02  3.830550e-02  3.292263e-02
genG07      -0.03315373 -1.607158e-17 -1.577377e-17  3.295262e-02  3.589269e-02  3.313738e-02  3.293607e-02
genG08      -0.03596202 -1.740363e-17 -1.705130e-17  3.898537e-02  3.875395e-02  3.828164e-02  3.320368e-02
genG09      -0.03340814 -1.616739e-17 -1.583978e-17  3.625000e-02  3.342494e-02  3.310418e-02  3.298899e-02
genG10      -0.03362605 -1.627089e-17 -1.593920e-17  3.670237e-02  3.360970e-02  3.318702e-02  3.338845e-02
genG11      -0.03320671 -1.609684e-17 -1.579813e-17  3.305207e-02  3.272121e-02  3.599864e-02  3.300232e-02
genG12      -0.03600456 -1.744900e-17 -1.712104e-17  3.628894e-02  3.572017e-02  3.572017e-02  3.297496e-02
genG13      -0.03641734 -1.762400e-17 -1.726723e-17  3.947686e-02  3.895789e-02  3.616288e-02  3.337442e-02
genG14      -0.03360572 -1.628857e-17 -1.598459e-17  3.363564e-02  3.358583e-02  3.638085e-02  3.081398e-02
genG15      -0.03340511 -1.616789e-17 -1.584227e-17  3.602945e-02  3.618024e-02  3.293344e-02  3.061337e-02
genG16      -0.03623006 -1.756087e-17 -1.723344e-17  3.623006e-02  3.617117e-02  3.623006e-02  3.298325e-02
genG17      -0.03337493 -1.617715e-17 -1.587571e-17  3.335536e-02  3.290597e-02  3.593240e-02  3.059671e-02
genG18      -0.03643117 -1.763482e-17 -1.728204e-17  3.903518e-02  3.599214e-02  3.917013e-02  3.318708e-02
genG19      -0.03338819 -1.618507e-17 -1.588500e-17  3.320363e-02  3.595894e-02  3.340499e-02  3.059671e-02
genG20      -0.03592887 -1.738908e-17 -1.703857e-17  3.878400e-02  3.848634e-02  3.846640e-02  3.592590e-02
genG21      -0.03620013 -1.752083e-17 -1.716815e-17  3.902507e-02  3.572846e-02  3.618024e-02  3.339931e-02
genG22      -0.03641462 -1.762483e-17 -1.727023e-17  3.923655e-02  3.611066e-02  3.898537e-02  3.592590e-02
genG23      -0.03624963 -1.756763e-17 -1.723731e-17  3.655082e-02  3.878716e-02  3.578067e-02  3.298899e-02
genG24      -0.03638470 -1.763340e-17 -1.730215e-17  3.665273e-02  3.870431e-02  3.589919e-02  3.330560e-02
                   genG06        genG07        genG08        genG09        genG10        genG11        genG12
(Intercept) -3.596555e-02 -3.315373e-02 -3.596202e-02 -3.340814e-02 -3.362605e-02 -3.320671e-02 -3.600456e-02
repR2       -1.743436e-17 -1.607158e-17 -1.740363e-17 -1.616739e-17 -1.627089e-17 -1.609684e-17 -1.744900e-17
repR3       -1.711101e-17 -1.577377e-17 -1.705130e-17 -1.583978e-17 -1.593920e-17 -1.579813e-17 -1.712104e-17
genG02       3.577827e-02  3.295262e-02  3.898537e-02  3.625000e-02  3.670237e-02  3.305207e-02  3.628894e-02
genG03       3.571109e-02  3.589269e-02  3.875395e-02  3.342494e-02  3.360970e-02  3.272121e-02  3.572017e-02
genG04       3.830550e-02  3.313738e-02  3.828164e-02  3.310418e-02  3.318702e-02  3.599864e-02  3.572017e-02
genG05       3.292263e-02  3.293607e-02  3.320368e-02  3.298899e-02  3.338845e-02  3.300232e-02  3.297496e-02
genG06       7.189789e-02  3.571115e-02  3.567794e-02  3.571443e-02  3.317698e-02  3.324339e-02  3.856500e-02
genG07       3.571115e-02  6.630747e-02  3.317008e-02  3.059632e-02  3.054973e-02  3.041477e-02  3.277359e-02
genG08       3.567794e-02  3.317008e-02  7.192404e-02  3.576444e-02  3.364240e-02  3.293867e-02  3.553540e-02
genG09       3.571443e-02  3.059632e-02  3.576444e-02  6.678306e-02  3.386365e-02  3.041472e-02  3.603776e-02
genG10       3.317698e-02  3.054973e-02  3.364240e-02  3.386365e-02  6.725210e-02  3.082820e-02  3.642389e-02
genG11       3.324339e-02  3.041477e-02  3.293867e-02  3.041472e-02  3.082820e-02  6.641342e-02  3.558522e-02
genG12       3.856500e-02  3.277359e-02  3.553540e-02  3.603776e-02  3.642389e-02  3.558522e-02  7.200911e-02
genG13       3.616944e-02  3.315645e-02  3.900443e-02  3.386345e-02  3.665519e-02  3.337442e-02  3.881618e-02
genG14       3.360899e-02  3.083058e-02  3.615960e-02  3.058268e-02  3.098214e-02  3.342423e-02  3.319293e-02
genG15       3.339931e-02  3.318392e-02  3.597893e-02  3.363974e-02  3.110229e-02  3.019719e-02  3.344411e-02
genG16       3.902507e-02  3.575774e-02  3.580738e-02  3.322357e-02  3.342494e-02  3.347475e-02  3.628894e-02
genG17       3.616698e-02  3.312355e-02  3.291961e-02  3.081171e-02  3.080085e-02  3.341110e-02  3.597135e-02
genG18       3.900853e-02  3.335485e-02  3.638863e-02  3.342197e-02  3.382716e-02  3.369221e-02  3.647371e-02
genG19       3.576407e-02  3.337139e-02  3.594510e-02  3.058288e-02  3.059691e-02  3.298919e-02  3.314312e-02
genG20       3.546325e-02  3.547689e-02  3.872035e-02  3.337473e-02  3.614981e-02  3.317003e-02  3.551880e-02
genG21       3.620341e-02  3.310423e-02  3.574752e-02  3.365951e-02  3.645125e-02  3.599870e-02  3.903415e-02
genG22       3.641816e-02  3.315102e-02  3.617652e-02  3.360931e-02  3.407512e-02  3.621622e-02  3.649031e-02
genG23       3.626643e-02  3.320323e-02  3.624609e-02  3.369549e-02  3.626996e-02  3.303900e-02  3.886599e-02
genG24       3.897532e-02  3.353387e-02  3.611666e-02  3.638772e-02  3.406508e-02  3.336135e-02  3.923552e-02
                   genG13        genG14        genG15        genG16        genG17        genG18        genG19
(Intercept) -3.641734e-02 -3.360572e-02 -3.340511e-02 -3.623006e-02 -3.337493e-02 -3.643117e-02 -3.338819e-02
repR2       -1.762400e-17 -1.628857e-17 -1.616789e-17 -1.756087e-17 -1.617715e-17 -1.763482e-17 -1.618507e-17
repR3       -1.726723e-17 -1.598459e-17 -1.584227e-17 -1.723344e-17 -1.587571e-17 -1.728204e-17 -1.588500e-17
genG02       3.947686e-02  3.363564e-02  3.602945e-02  3.623006e-02  3.335536e-02  3.903518e-02  3.320363e-02
genG03       3.895789e-02  3.358583e-02  3.618024e-02  3.617117e-02  3.290597e-02  3.599214e-02  3.595894e-02
genG04       3.616288e-02  3.638085e-02  3.293344e-02  3.623006e-02  3.593240e-02  3.917013e-02  3.340499e-02
genG05       3.337442e-02  3.081398e-02  3.061337e-02  3.298325e-02  3.059671e-02  3.318708e-02  3.059671e-02
genG06       3.616944e-02  3.360899e-02  3.339931e-02  3.902507e-02  3.616698e-02  3.900853e-02  3.576407e-02
genG07       3.315645e-02  3.083058e-02  3.318392e-02  3.575774e-02  3.312355e-02  3.335485e-02  3.337139e-02
genG08       3.900443e-02  3.615960e-02  3.597893e-02  3.580738e-02  3.291961e-02  3.638863e-02  3.594510e-02
genG09       3.386345e-02  3.058268e-02  3.363974e-02  3.322357e-02  3.081171e-02  3.342197e-02  3.058288e-02
genG10       3.665519e-02  3.098214e-02  3.110229e-02  3.342494e-02  3.080085e-02  3.382716e-02  3.059691e-02
genG11       3.337442e-02  3.342423e-02  3.019719e-02  3.347475e-02  3.341110e-02  3.369221e-02  3.298919e-02
genG12       3.881618e-02  3.319293e-02  3.344411e-02  3.628894e-02  3.597135e-02  3.647371e-02  3.314312e-02
genG13       7.280147e-02  3.405171e-02  3.386017e-02  3.668184e-02  3.336109e-02  3.944037e-02  3.614627e-02
genG14       3.405171e-02  6.717822e-02  3.079737e-02  3.643066e-02  3.101862e-02  3.666196e-02  3.382041e-02
genG15       3.386017e-02  3.079737e-02  6.677701e-02  3.343504e-02  3.312078e-02  3.358665e-02  3.084455e-02
genG16       3.668184e-02  3.643066e-02  3.343504e-02  7.246011e-02  3.367612e-02  3.950749e-02  3.621012e-02
genG17       3.336109e-02  3.101862e-02  3.312078e-02  3.367612e-02  6.671664e-02  3.620038e-02  3.080085e-02
genG18       3.944037e-02  3.666196e-02  3.358665e-02  3.950749e-02  3.620038e-02  7.286234e-02  3.385381e-02
genG19       3.614627e-02  3.382041e-02  3.084455e-02  3.621012e-02  3.080085e-02  3.385381e-02  6.674318e-02
genG20       3.639745e-02  3.594491e-02  3.337196e-02  3.590930e-02  3.309034e-02  3.615991e-02  3.335479e-02
genG21       3.665519e-02  3.359239e-02  3.339179e-02  3.882447e-02  3.598538e-02  3.670243e-02  3.315715e-02
genG22       3.924228e-02  3.407159e-02  3.338856e-02  3.925649e-02  3.382728e-02  3.967526e-02  3.358937e-02
genG23       3.949346e-02  3.619609e-02  3.606506e-02  3.910476e-02  3.341110e-02  3.927569e-02  3.366647e-02
genG24       3.687316e-02  3.357579e-02  3.638167e-02  3.940804e-02  3.379407e-02  3.687020e-02  3.357276e-02
                   genG20        genG21        genG22        genG23        genG24
(Intercept) -3.592887e-02 -3.620013e-02 -3.641462e-02 -3.624963e-02 -3.638470e-02
repR2       -1.738908e-17 -1.752083e-17 -1.762483e-17 -1.756763e-17 -1.763340e-17
repR3       -1.703857e-17 -1.716815e-17 -1.727023e-17 -1.723731e-17 -1.730215e-17
genG02       3.878400e-02  3.902507e-02  3.923655e-02  3.655082e-02  3.665273e-02
genG03       3.848634e-02  3.572846e-02  3.611066e-02  3.878716e-02  3.870431e-02
genG04       3.846640e-02  3.618024e-02  3.898537e-02  3.578067e-02  3.589919e-02
genG05       3.592590e-02  3.339931e-02  3.592590e-02  3.298899e-02  3.330560e-02
genG06       3.546325e-02  3.620341e-02  3.641816e-02  3.626643e-02  3.897532e-02
genG07       3.547689e-02  3.310423e-02  3.315102e-02  3.320323e-02  3.353387e-02
genG08       3.872035e-02  3.574752e-02  3.617652e-02  3.624609e-02  3.611666e-02
genG09       3.337473e-02  3.365951e-02  3.360931e-02  3.369549e-02  3.638772e-02
genG10       3.614981e-02  3.645125e-02  3.407512e-02  3.626996e-02  3.406508e-02
genG11       3.317003e-02  3.599870e-02  3.621622e-02  3.303900e-02  3.336135e-02
genG12       3.551880e-02  3.903415e-02  3.649031e-02  3.886599e-02  3.923552e-02
genG13       3.639745e-02  3.665519e-02  3.924228e-02  3.949346e-02  3.687316e-02
genG14       3.594491e-02  3.359239e-02  3.407159e-02  3.619609e-02  3.357579e-02
genG15       3.337196e-02  3.339179e-02  3.338856e-02  3.606506e-02  3.638167e-02
genG16       3.590930e-02  3.882447e-02  3.925649e-02  3.910476e-02  3.940804e-02
genG17       3.309034e-02  3.598538e-02  3.382728e-02  3.341110e-02  3.379407e-02
genG18       3.615991e-02  3.670243e-02  3.967526e-02  3.927569e-02  3.687020e-02
genG19       3.335479e-02  3.315715e-02  3.358937e-02  3.366647e-02  3.357276e-02
genG20       7.182453e-02  3.846974e-02  3.637215e-02  3.596504e-02  3.589623e-02
genG21       3.846974e-02  7.236705e-02  3.944125e-02  3.648774e-02  3.919663e-02
genG22       3.637215e-02  3.944125e-02  7.279604e-02  3.670198e-02  3.919360e-02
genG23       3.596504e-02  3.648774e-02  3.670198e-02  7.246605e-02  3.946379e-02
genG24       3.589623e-02  3.919663e-02  3.919360e-02  3.946379e-02  7.276939e-02
```

How to get the variance-covariances of the value at each level instead of that for deviation from base level (first level) ?

For example the variance-covariance matrix of repR1, repR2, repR3 (3x3 matrix) and genG01 to genG24 (24x24 matrix).

Comment: Just apply a linear transform matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lme4)
library(agridat)
data(john.alpha)

# models
model1 <- lmer(yield ~ 1 + rep + (1|gen) + (1|rep:block), john.alpha)
model2 <- lmer(yield ~ 1 + rep + gen + (1|rep:block), john.alpha)
```

As @ZheyuanLi says, you "just apply a linear transform matrix".  The shortcut is to use the `lsmeans` package, which does this for you:

```
library(lsmeans)
vcov(lsmeans(model1,specs="rep"))
vcov(lsmeans(model2,specs="rep"))
vcov(lsmeans(model2,specs="gen"))
```